# Maven skip deploy & push only Docker images

Tags: maven, docker

I have both deploy plugin and dockerize plugin in my Maven project.

Deploy plugin,

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Dockerize plugin,

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>docker</id>
            <properties>
                <assembly.skipAssembly>true</assembly.skipAssembly>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.docker.plugin}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>dockerize-app</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>${docker.image-prefix}${project.artifactId}</repository>
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                            </buildArgs>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <include>${project.artifactId}.war</include>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

I have following use cases.

1. Deploy artifacts alone
2. Deploy Docker image alone
3. Deploy artifact & Docker image

To achieve this, I added Docker plugin under profile. So that, Docker image will be deployed on passing the profile name.

> **mvn deploy**

The above command will deploy just the artifacts.

> **mvn deploy -P docker**

The above command will deploy artifacts & Docker image.

But, I am unable to just deploy the Docker image.

To just deploy the Docker image, I am adding the below config in the deploy plugin,

```
<configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
```

Or, setting default-deploy to none.

```
<execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
```

The above 2 approaches needs pom change.

1. The other approach would be to create a profile for deploy also so that we can pass the profile we want.

Is there any other better approach? Or, is it possible with the Maven arguments to skip deploy?

Comment: I hope you don't have configured maven-deploy-plugin yourself? Only the version via pluginManagement ?

Comment: Yes, via pluginManagement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can do what you want by using properties instead of profiles. 
Just remove the `docker` profile and put the configuration directly inside your POM, and the following commands should work :

- `mvn -Dmaven.deploy.skip deploy` to deploy only Docker images (default `deploy` phase is skipped)
- `mvn -Ddockerfile.skip deploy` to deploy only artifacts to your repository manager. Options to skip goals (like `dockerfile.skip`) are described on the [`dockerfile-maven-plugin` documentation](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/tree/v1.4.4#skip-docker-goals-bound-to-maven-phases)
- `mvn deploy` to deploy both (artifacts and Docker images)